# General question about nearest neighbor data structures

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nearest-neighbor, flann

I want to improve the speed of my feature matching algorithm. The matching is based on comparing feature A with circularly shifted feature B. The shifting is performed N times (for orientation invariance). The distance between A and B is the minimal value of the distance between A and the shifted B.

Considering this distance, I cannot use a KD tree or the FLANN library.

What kind of solutions could be applied in my case in order to speed up the NN search? Is there any c++ library that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Is the shifting quantity (distance) uniform?  You could use a {circular} array and shift the index of A to get to B.  By shifting I mean `int B_index = (A_Index + Shift_Amount) % (Array_Size);`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews. Thanks. Yes, the shift amount is known. My problem is not with the circular shift  My objective is to speed up the NN search using the distance described in my question.

Comment: @trincot I don't even know about this. I just checked my few questions here and I don't seem to find a button for answer acceptance, maybe you could help ?

Comment: There is a grey checkmark next to each answer. Just click the one that should be accepted. Normally you would have received automated email notifications from Stack Overflow about this. And it doesn't hurt, even after that many years, to follow [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @trincot thanks. So far I am hoping to get additional suggestions for this question.

Comment: @trincot I only see an upward arrow and a flag to the left of each comment. Where is the grey checkmark? I think the acceptance is for answers rather than comments?

Comment: Indeed, it is for answers. You have asked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307723/lounice?tab=questions) in the past, and I am referring to those. Not to the comments above.